# How to create a @Provides function for a class that have @AssistedInject with android Hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt, android-paging-3

So I'm trying to figure out how to create a @Provides function for a class that have @Assisted inject, is it possible or even a good practice?

I'm trying to inject a Pager from the android Paging library 3 into my Repository, I already managed to do it when the PagingSource don't have dynamic(runtime) arguments. Here is my code:

```kotlin
@Qualifier
annotation class ComicPager

private const val PAGE_SIZE = 10

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
internal object PagerModule {
    @ComicPager
    @Provides
    fun provideComicPager(
        config: PagingConfig,
        pagingSource: ComicPagingSource
    ): Pager<Int, ComicDto> = 
Pager(config = config, pagingSourceFactory = { pagingSource })
    
        @Provides
        fun providePagingConfig(): PagingConfig = PagingConfig(pageSize = PAGE_SIZE)
}
```

And this is my `ComicPagingSource` constructor:

```kotlin
internal class ComicPagingSource @Inject constructor(
private val comicDataSource: ComicDataSource
) : PagingSource<Int, ComicDto>() {
    // Paging logic here...
}
```

And the ComicRepository where the Pager is injected:

```kotlin
@Singleton
internal class ComicRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val comicDataSource: ComicDataSource,
    private val pager: Pager<Int, ComicDto> // <- Pager injected!
) {


    fun getComics(): Flow<PagingData<Comic>> {
        return pager.flow
            .map { pagingData ->
                pagingData.map { comic -> comic.toComic() }
            }
    }
}
```

So far so good the `Pager` is provided to the `ComicRepository`.

Now I want to do the same thing for another PagingSource that I have that receives a `id` as a parameter in the constructor, I thought that would be simple to just pass the parameter to the provider method but I can't find a way to do it. This is the constructor for the other PagingSource:

```kotlin
internal class CreatorPagingSource @AssistedInject constructor(
    @Assisted private val creatorId: Int,
    private val creatorDataSource: CreatorDataSource
) : PagingSource<Int, ComicDto>() {
    // Paging logic here...
}

@AssistedFactory
internal interface Factory {
    fun create(creatorId: Int): CreatorPagingSource
}


internal class CreatorPagingSourceFactoryProvider @Inject constructor(
    private val creatorDataSource: CreatorDataSource
) :
    CreatorPagingSource.Factory {
    override fun create(creatorId: Int): CreatorPagingSource =
        CreatorPagingSource(creatorId, creatorDataSource = creatorDataSource)
}
```

This is what I accomplished until now on my repository:

```kotlin
internal class CreatorRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val pagingConfig: PagingConfig,
    private val pagingSourceFactoryProvider: PagingSourceFactoryProvider,
) {
    fun getCreatorComics(creatorId: Int): Flow<PagingData<Comic>> {
        return Pager(
            config = pagingConfig,
            pagingSourceFactory = { pagingSourceFactoryProvider.create(creatorId) } // <- Unable to inject the Pager because can't create a Provider to this injector
        ).flow
            .map { pagingData ->
                pagingData.map { comic -> comic.toComic() }
            }
    }
}
```

But it is not to my liking because I'm still creating the Pager inside the getCreatorComics methods, can someone help me figure out how to pass an @Assisted parameter to a @Provides or point me to a better direction?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you inject the factory because you will only be able to create the object at run time. You can delegate the creation itself, but someone has to create it.

If the problem is because you create concrete implementations and therefore couple implementations I can provide an example of how you can avoid this. I'm not sure it's necessarily better but let me explain the reasoning as I go.

First, I've noticed you've implemented `CreatorPagingSource.Factory` but since this is an `@AssisteFactory` dagger will create the implementation for you. So I'd remove the implementation.

I often prefer to depend on interfaces rather than concrete classes, so for these cases I often do the following:

```kotlin
interface PagingSourceFactory {
   fun create(creatorId: Int): PagingSource<Int, ComicDto>
}
```

This is an interface for a `PagingSource` factory. You can now implement it using `@AssistedFactory` like so:

```kotlin
@AssistedFactory
internal interface Factory : PagingSourceFactory {
   override fun create(creatorId: Int): CreatorPagingSource
}
```

Notice how we extend the factory and override the `create` method changing it's return type. This is required by `AssistedInject` - to return the concrete implementation and not an abstraction. This is legal in Java - you can change the return type as long as it's within the bounds of the method it overrides.

You can now inject only `PagingSourceFactory` where you need it by writing a provider:

```kotlin
@Binds
fun bindPagingSourceFactory(
  creatorPagingSourceFactory: Factory, // this is the AssistedFactory you've defined
): PagingSourceFactory
```

And the repo can become:

```kotlin
internal class CreatorRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val pagingConfig: PagingConfig,
    private val pagingSourceFactory: PagingSourceFactory,
) {
    fun getCreatorComics(creatorId: Int): Flow<PagingData<Comic>> {
        return Pager(
            config = pagingConfig,
            pagingSourceFactory = { pagingSourceFactory.create(creatorId) } 
        ).flow
            .map { pagingData ->
                pagingData.map { comic -> comic.toComic() }
            }
    }
}
```

The difference is that you're now creating the `PagingSource<Int, ComicDto>` abstraction and your repository doesn't need to know about `CreatorPagingSource`. In the future you can change the dagger modules to return other implementations. I think it's even better like this for testing and injecting mock factories that create mock objects.

Not sure if this will help your issue but I think it could be useful.

Comment: I see your suggestion as an improvement @Fred, thanks for writing it up. Unfortunately the main problem persists, the `Pager` class is still instantiated inside the `getCreatorComics` method. If you needed to inject the Pager into `CreatorRepository` using hilt, how would you accomplish that?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant with my first paragraph @GibranLyra. Someone has to create the `Pager` and because it's runtime dependencies I don't really know of a way to do it through a dagger graph. You could inject it into the `CreatorRepository` by passing it as an `@Assisted` dependency, but you're just delaying your problem :) In any case, I think this is a great question and I'm super interested in all the answers coming here.